# Not able to Authenticate SSO on Klipfolio

Tags: c#, cookies, single-sign-on, restsharp, klipfolio

I am working on SSO for Klipfolio. I am using restsharp for SSO. Everything is perfect I got success response. I also received cookies in response, but not able to redirect to their dashboard.
Here is my code

```
            var client = new RestClient("https://app.klipfolio.com/users/sso_auth");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("KF-SSO", AuthData["KF-SSO"]);
            request.AddParameter("KF-Company", AuthData["KF-Company"]);
            response = client.Execute(request);
            CookieContainer CookiesContainer = new CookieContainer();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                foreach (var Cookie in response.Cookies)
                {
                    CookiesContainer.Add(new Cookie(Cookie.Name, Cookie.Value, Cookie.Path, Cookie.Domain));
                }
            client.CookieContainer = CookiesContainer;
            KlipfolioDataModel objKlipfolioDataModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KlipfolioDataModel>(response.Content);
            return objKlipfolioDataModel;
            }
            else
               return new KlipfolioDataModel();
```

If i am doing same thing from AJAX, i am able to redirect to Klipoflio dashboard

```
function ssoAuth() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://app.klipfolio.com/users/sso_auth",
        type: "post",
        async: false,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        headers: {
            "KF-SSO": ssoToken,
            "KF-Company": ssoCompany
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log("sso auth failed", err)
            var errMsg = JSON.parse(err.responseText);
            console.log(errMsg)
            $('#result').html("<h2 class='fail'>SSO Failed<h2><p>Error: (#" + errMsg.error_code + ") "
                + errMsg.error_message + "</p>");
        }
    })
}
```

I don't know where i am wrong? Help me to figure out this thing.

Comment: As far as I know you don't need to copy the cookies. You could just use the same `CookieContainer` for both requests.

Comment: Are you planning to use it in a Web application (for example C# in ASP.NET)?